# Was Spock's Calculation Wrong?

Tags: star-trek

In TOS episode The Trouble With Tribbles Spock tells Jones that it will take him about 17.9 years to pick up the Tribbles. But on the DS9 episode Trials and Tribble-ations at the end the Tribbles are still there in Quark's place and DS9 is about 75 years after. Did Spock make a mistake?

Comment: Which Tribbles are you talking about?  The ones on the Promenade, right at the very end of the episode?

Answer (score 14):

## The *TOS* and *DS9* tribble episodes are set at the *same time* and portray the *same events*.

In the *DS9* episode "Trials and Tribble-ations", Sisko, Dax, Bashir, O'Brien, and Worf go back in time (using a Bajoran orb) to the *same time* as the *TOS* episode.  In other words, we are seeing the tribbles on Station K-7 at the same time as Spock was seeing them in *TOS*, not 75 years later.

Here are Kirk, Spock, Sisko, and Dax all together in the same scene:

[image]

As for the tribbles on the Promenade at the end of the *DS9* episode, they are the progeny of tribbles brought back with Sisko and the others to the 24th Century.  They are not the result of 75 years of breeding.